# React async / await and setState not rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, web3js

I have a problem with rerender after getting result from web3 call - execution of smart contract. Code below:

```js
this.setState({ loading: true });

await contractInstance.methods
                .myMethod(params)
                .send({ from: myAccount, gas: 10000000 })
                .then(async function(receipt) {
                    let txHash = receipt.transactionHash;
                    ...

                    // await saveToDb(thHash, ...)

                    this.setState({ dateToDisplay: myVar.publishDate, loading: false });
```

..

and the render is as below:

```
render() {
        if (!this.state.loading) {
            return (
            ...
             {this.state.dateToDisplay}
```

I have other methods where this pattern works, but here I could not make it work. I tried to make setState async and await it, like:

```
setStateAsync(state) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.setState(state, resolve);
        });
    }
```

But does not help either.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you combine `await` and promises?

The point of `await` is to stop the execution at that point and wait for the promise to resolve. The `const result = await promise;` is a replacement for `promise.then(result => ...)`.

You could do this:

```
const receipt = await contractInstance.methods
    .myMethod(params)
    .send({ from: myAccount, gas: 10000000 });

let txHash = receipt.transactionHash;
...

// await saveToDb(thHash, ...)

this.setState({ dateToDisplay: myVar.publishDate, loading: false });
```

In my opinion, this makes the code less complex and easier to follow what's going on and make sense of it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change Async function to arrow function or bind the function so that this will be available inside that function

```
     await contractInstance.methods
            .myMethod(params)
            .send({ from: myAccount, gas: 10000000 })
            .then(async receipt => {
                let txHash = receipt.transactionHash;
                ...

                // await saveToDb(thHash, ...)

                this.setState({ dateToDisplay: myVar.publishDate, loading: false });
```

Or bind it

```
    await contractInstance.methods
            .myMethod(params)
            .send({ from: myAccount, gas: 10000000 })
            .then(async function(receipt) {
                let txHash = receipt.transactionHash;
                ...

                // await saveToDb(thHash, ...)

                this.setState({ dateToDisplay: myVar.publishDate, loading: false });
            }.bind(this))
```